# Write/Read structure with pointers to file

Tags: c, file, struct, io

I have to write a structure to a file so i can read it in later. The struct is:

```
struct prog{
    char* title;
    char* channel;
    struct tm* start;
    struct tm* end;
    float review;
    enum soort sort;
    union type *type;
};

union type{
    struct serie *ep;
    struct film *mov;
};

struct serie{
    int seznum;
    int epnum;
    char* eptitle;
};

struct film{
    char* reg;
    char* act;
   char* genre;
};

enum sort { film, serie }
```

So you can see that there are pointers to strings and the struct tm (from time.h). I can't figure out how to write it to a binary file, all i can do is write it string by string but there must be a more efficient way to write the previous struct.
I think the problem starts with the char* and the pointers to the tm structs because the program is now going to write the adress of the start of a string or the adress of the tm struct. I wan't to write the string and not the adress to a file. I tried with record I/O but it writes the adresses so i can't read them later. 
Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind SO is not a "do my homework" site.  What have you tried?  Why is it not working?  What error are you getting?  Why do you think it's not working - i.e. what specific problem are you having?

Comment: I've added some information

Comment: So you want to write the structure data to a file in order to later read it back into memory.  This process is called marshalling ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29 ) or serializing.  You need to specify a format for the structure data in the file and write functions to convert to and from this format.  It can be a binary format or a textual format.  Text formats, such as json, are preferable, as they are more readable and portable.  Binary formats may be slightly smaller and faster to read and write.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so what you say is: I have to write all the information as String to a file and then write a function to read them back in?

Comment: What I am saying is: you cannot just dump the struct object to a file with `fwrite` and expect to read it back later with `fread`. You need to write a function that converts the structure to an external representation such as json, and another that will read the external representation and allocate a new structure.  I assume the pointers point to malloc'ed structure, unions and strings.

Comment: Why do the `struct tm*` fields have to be pointers, and not the actual data?

Comment: It's best to avoid binary file representation unless you have a very good reason for doing so, because if your program breaks or is unavailable your data is just unusable junk. Much better to have a textual representation that be easily accessed, especially if it is in a format that is recognised by other programs. I suggest using a `tab` separated format, then your data can be loaded into a spreadsheet if required, and is reasonably easy for you to both write and read in your own program.

Comment: You will need to look up 'serialization' and apply it to the structures. You'll need to decide on a system for knowing how long fields are ([TLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) — type, length, value — for example, or if you're into BDSM, then maybe you could use ASN.1). And you'll need to decide on a suitable encoding for the `struct tm` values; you might decide that a Unix timestamp value is more convenient, or you could go for a string representation (based on ISO 8601, so 2015-03-07 12:28:28 -08:00, for example). But because of all the pointers, you have to work quite hard.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at time_t or other alternatives which can store time in a single integer timestamp. You can also use a database or a simple file storage class.

Otherwise you can't really improve this with native C functions. You could remove pointers and use fixed character arrays like so:

```
struct T_film
{
   char text[50];
   int  i;
};

struct T_prog
{
   char title[50];
   tm start;
   tm end;
   T_film film;
};

T_prog data;//initialize...
fwrite(&data, 1, sizeof(T_prog), fout);

fseek(fin,0,0);
fread(&data, 1, sizeof(T_prog), fin);
```

Now the structure has a fixed pattern and everything can be stored in binary. BUT, this can be even more inefficient. The size of text is too short, or too long with extra blank space which takes too long to read. It's not portable either. So you may want to stick to pointers and reading/writing with makeshift methods.

You can also separate fixed sized data and put them in a separate structure. Write the fixed sized data in one block, then write the character strings one by one.